# Area of a circle is $A = \pi r^2$. Is it possible that both $A$ and $r$ are perfect integers.

Tags: number-theory, irrational-numbers, pi

Can you produce an example where both the area of a circle and it's radius are integers?

Comment: No, if that were true then $r^2$ would be an integer and then $\pi=\frac{A}{r^2}$ would be rational, which it isn't.

Comment: If r = 0 because then A = 0. But that's hardly an example, is it? Otherwise Tom answered it.

Comment: @Tom: That's an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @Asaf I suppose, I wrote it up as one at first but I didn't feel like I had put enough work into it to make it an answer! I was sure that someone else would point out the exact same thing (and I hate it when some questions receive many almost identical answers). If no-one did I would have changed it into an answer at some point for completeness.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$r\neq 0\;,\;\pi r^2\;,\;r\in\Bbb N\implies \pi\in\Bbb Q\;,\;\text{which is false}$$

Comment: OK, then is it correct to say that at least one among A and r has to be irrational.

Comment: Yes, it is correct.